# In Lua, how to set a nil parameter to some default value correctly?

Tags: function, parameters, lua

For Lua code below:

```
local function foo(x, y, z)
    local x = x or true
    local y = y or 1234
    z = z or "default"
end
```

I always thought the meaning of these three lines inside the function is:

If x/y/z is nil, x/y/z is set to true/1234/"default". Otherwise, it remains whatever it is. Therefore, I have such a line in many places to set a parameter to some default value in case it might be passed into a function as nil.

However, it seems not totally correct in my experiments. I am not sure where I learnt this Lua coding concept. How to do it correctly?

Comment: It'd fail if I pass `false` as the first parameter

Comment: The style is to not put `local` in front. (That actually creates a new variable. You could see that in some debuggers.)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The method will work as long as your boolean(?) variable `x` was not initialised as `false`. If you only want to use defaults against `nil` values, the `a or b` method is correct.

If your variable can be `false`, you'd have to use a strict if-then block:

```
if x == nil then x = true end
```

You can see a few more methods/examples about ternary operators on [lua wiki](http://lua-users.org/wiki/TernaryOperator).

Comment: Yes, that's one thing I found out that if the variable passed in is false, it becomes true instead of staying as false. That's why I started to worrying using statement like these. So, is it the only case? Even if it is, I better start using the strict if-then to avoid any confusion.

Comment: @Joe See the Lua manual on conditionals. `false` and `nil` are falsey; All other values are truthy.

Comment: @hjpotter92: To be more precise, the 'or' method will work for all cases regardless of the passed-in value being nil, true, false, or anything else, EXCEPT when the default value in the function has to be true .  But if the default has to be false, 'or' will still work (against nil) as nil or false is false, not nil.

Comment: @tonypdmtr What if I call the function as `foo(false, 3)` I want my `x` to be `false` here. `z`; otoh can be the default value

Comment: @hjpotter92 Maybe you misread what I said: "EXCEPT when the default value in the function has to be true", which is this case.  I simply attempted to make it clearer that it is not the caller's value that matters but the required default in the function.  If we needed a false default, then calling with either nil or false would give us false, right?

Answer (score 2):

There exists one more strict method if you want to be able pass `nil` as argument(e.g. you want distinguish `foo(1,2,nil)` and `foo(1,2)`)

```
function foo(...)
  local n,x,y,z = select('#', ...), ...
  if n < 3 then z = default end
  if n < 2 then y = default end
  if n < 1 then x = default end
  -- here x,y or z  can be nil
  ...
end
```

But you have to be shure you know what you doing because it may be not expected behavior for users of your function.

Answer (score 0):

This should work as expected:

```
function foo(x, y, z)
    x = (x == nil) or x
    y = (y == nil and 1234) or y
    z = (z == nil and "default") or z
    print(x, y, z)
end

> foo()
true    1234    default
> foo(false, false, "me")
false   false   me
> foo(nil, 50, "me")
true    50  me
```